# How to create Polygon using Lat Long as coordinate using Google S2 Library in JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, android, python

I am using **GOOGLE S2** Library to create **geofence**.

I have created **rectangle** by using **latitude** and **longitude**  as coordinate in java but I am not able to create **polygon** by using **latitude** and **longitude** coordinate.

Could you please help me on this.

This is code for rectangular geofence in java:

```
   Double lo_latDegrees = 51.6934844;
   Double lo_lngDegrees = -63.568821;
    //12.960045, 77.640189
   Double hi_latDegrees = 51.844379;
   Double hi_lngDegrees = -63.169301;
   System.out.println("creating a rectangle");
   S2LatLngRect s2latlongRect = new 
   S2LatLngRect(S2LatLng.fromDegrees(lo_latDegrees, lo_lngDegrees),
   S2LatLng.fromDegrees(hi_latDegrees, hi_lngDegrees));
```

And for polygon I have tried something like that:

```
private static final String RECTANGLE1 = "10:11, 11:11, 12:11, 
   12:10, 11:10, 10:10;";  
   S2Polygon region = Utilities.makePolygon(RECTANGLE1);
   System.out.println("creating region");
```

Help me on this.

Thanks in advance !!!!!

Comment: You may take a look at Path2D.Double https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html

Comment: Can You provide some other way by using google s2 library only